# Can we (I) mark all the "What is this icon next to the player's name" as duplicates

Tags: discussion

If you [go to the roblox tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) like the last six questions are all "what is this foo icon next to the player's name" and the answer is always "it's game specific". Can these all be duplicates?

[image]

Comment: There should probably be a canonical "What does this icon next to Roblox usernames mean?" question.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 ehh, in the future it wont be but anyway there's no reason *not* to and it takes like 20-30 seconds to do so it doesnt really matter

Comment: @galacticninja That sounds like a good solution - can you post that as an answer?

Comment: [Similar question on Android Meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2433/205764).

Comment: FYI: Roblox staff team is rather foolish and questionable with their moves sometimes, and sometimes don't even bother to tell everyone about their new updates sometimes, so I can't argue with these people.  Also, the people saying it's game specific are just *guessing*, and the ones that indeed say it's not actually have **proof** for that and have a positive score. Regardless I think making a single post for all of them is a bad idea and the staff might as well just do that on their own [dev forum](https://devforum.roblox.com/) as usual.

Answer (score 9):

Should we mark them as all duplicates of each other? **No.** They are asking about different symbols, so marking them as duplicates of each other doesn't make sense.

As stated in this question's comments, we should create a canonical instead that contains all possible symbols, then mark all the symbol questions as duplicate of *that* instead.

According to a comment on this answer, symbols vary between games, so we may instead have to tell users to consult the game creator.

We have also agreed that the best user to create said canonical would be a Roblox player themselves, so if you would like to volunteer yourself, go ahead and create it. Be sure to explain clearly why the icons are game-specific, and give examples of how two of the same symbol might mean different things in different games.

Comment: There is not all possible - anyone can make a game and anyone can add their own symbol

Comment: can we just do that now then or should we wait for this to reach a few upvotes?

Comment: The user that will create the canonical post should preferably be a Roblox player. I don't play Roblox so I'm not the best person to create the canonical post. If we do proceed to make a canonical post, we can refer to the similar question and answer here as a guide: [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96496/4797) @Penguin Let's wait for a few votes or other answers first, to give time for others to join this discussion.

Comment: @galacticninja i dont think any of us three play roblox lmao, its just that these all have the same answer "its game specific" and i 100% know that anyone can make a game; im not too sure it matters if who makes it plays roblox

Comment: I do agree with the canonical answer solution (+1), but not with the idea we shouldn't VTC as duplicates (-1). Once the first is created, we'll have to the second anyway. These should have been two different answers, I think.

Comment: @Joachim You misunderstand. I *do* want to close the questions as duplicates. I was just pointing out in the first paragraph of my answer that we shouldn't close the questions *without* a canonical. So I do want to close all the questions as duplicates. Please read my answer more carefully and if you still don't get it, I can edit.

Comment: The first two paragraphs, in that case. But it was not entirely clear, no.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 im mot exactly sure how you could even make that more clear? I dont think you need to edit it, ur probably good

Comment: Best you could do is edit the mini-game/world name into the title, for relevance, since a question is "What is the [where it is] icon in [game/world name]?" when the search term is likely "roblox [game name] [where it is]", and then there's the issue of ambiguity between similar [where it is].

Comment: @aytimothy There are way too many Roblox games to create a question for each and every one of them.